# How can I get the username of the person executing my program?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi, posix

How can I get the username of the process owner (the user who is executing my program) in C++?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Windows

[GetUserName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Example:

```
 char user_name[UNLEN+1];
 DWORD user_name_size = sizeof(user_name);
 if (GetUserName(user_name, &user_name_size))
     cout << "Your user name is: " << user_name << endl;
 else
     /* Handle error */
```

---

## Linux

Look at [getpwuid](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpwuid.html):

> The getpwuid() function shall search
>   the user database for an entry with a
>   matching uid.
>
> The getpwuid() function shall return a
>   pointer to a struct passwd

The `struct passwd` will contain `char *pw_name`.

Use `getuid` to get the user id.

Comment: If you want to hard-code a buffer size, use 257 (UNLEN+1) this is the documented max size for a username on windows

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OSX:

```
getenv("USER");
```

On Linux:

```
getenv("USERNAME");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to the operating system. On Windows, use [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432(VS.85).aspx). On unix, use [getuid](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_getuid.htm).

Comment: The question is about the local user name, not the computer name.

Comment: This is the machine name not local user/logged on user.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, a thread can be impersonated, a process can not. To get the **process** owner you should call [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671(VS.85).aspx) with the TokenUser infoclass on your process token, this will give you a SID, this SID can be converted to a username with [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166(VS.85).aspx). If you don't care about thread vs process, GetUserName() is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a C++ related question. You can find information (not 100% sure) in the environment variables when using UNIX like systems. You can also use the 'id' program on these systems.

In general, the fastest way is to make a platform-dependent kernel / API call.

On windows under cmd.exe the USERNAME environment variable holds the username (which is also informational not factual). Search in WINAPI documentation for precise.

Comment: @Notinlist: what do you mean it's not a C++ related question? He's using C++. This makes the question C++ related. Maybe you come from places where "C++ related" means only standard C++ (such as #c++@irc.freenode.net), but here on SO this is considered very in topic :)

Comment: for future reference, on all systems (windows included) you can type: `whoami` to get the current username.